# What is the right way to update createdAt and updatedAt date fields for a document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a document collection called **schools** for which we have kept fields called **createdAt** and **updatedAt**. I'm updating these fields using Firestore cloud trigger functions in onCreate and onUpdate triggeres respectively.

The problem I'm facing here is, these field updates will call onUpdate trigger again unnecessarily. For these to handle, I've written an additional function called **skipOnUpdateTrigger**

```js
const excludeFields = ["createdAt", "UpdatedAt"]

shouldSkipOnUpdateTrigger = function(docDataOld, docDataNew, excludeFields){
    for(let i of excludeFields){
        if (docDataOld[i] !== docDataNew[i])
            return true;
 }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a better way I can handle this situation to avoid those extra triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I've found is to prevent the need for Cloud Functions altogether, and let the client include the `lastUpdated` value in each write with a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).

You can enforce this in security rules, by checking:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.lastUpdated == request.time
```

Comment: The link leads to "Update fields in nested objects" section. How it's related to timestamps?

Comment: Thanks for flagging. The documentation on server-side timestamps was moved into its own section: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp

Comment: FYI, this gives: Error saving rules – Line 8: Unexpected '='.

Comment: Oops, the expression was missing an `=`. Thanks for flagging

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea.  You have to compare the before and after snapshots to make sure that an update happened where you actually want to modify the timestamp.  There is no way to know *how* the change happened (it could be client or server), so you have to look at the data itself.

Comment: I tried with this solution and I'm confronting the change.before.updateTime and change.after.updateTime (to avoid an infinite update loop). The problem is those result the same from my onUpdate cloud function, so I think I have to go for Frank's solution and adding updatedAt to my PUT REST API